# Which maven pom.xml attribute must I define the webcontent project?

Tags: maven

Which maven pom.xml attribute must I define the webcontent (like xhtml pages and css, js, image resources)?
ps: I'm using eclipse IDE.

Comment: What do you mean? Why do you want to define that in pom.xml?

Comment: Because when I do 'Run Build', the generated war file doesn't contain my xhtml pages and others web resources.

Comment: Show your project structure and pom.

Answer (score 0):

```
<plugin>  
         <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>  
         <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>  
         <configuration>  
             <webappDirectory> ${basedir}/target/resources </webappDirectory>
```